# Complex If condition using regex on visualforce

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I'm trying to use `REGEX` into `AND` function, but I get this error:

> Error: Function REGEX may not be used in this type of formula

Code:

```
rendered="{!AND(condition1,REGEX(condition2 ,'A|B|C'))}">
```

Why I cant use a `REGEX` into an `AND` ?? There is a simpler way to do it?

**UPDATED**:
I found that `REGEX` is not avaidable to use on visualforce. Having say that, is there some nice workaround to do this ?

```
if(value in ['A','B','C'])
```

Comment: This function is available everywhere formulas exist except formula fields and custom buttons and links.

Comment: Is rendered="{! (value == 'A') || (value == 'B') || (value == 'C') }" an acceptable workaround?

Comment: thanks @jkraybill, that's what i was looking for... Pls, post it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: That makes no sense because REGEX is documented in the Visualforce Developer's Guide.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no regex, but for what you're doing, this should work just fine:

```
 rendered="{! (value == 'A') || (value == 'B') || (value == 'C') }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to put this formula into a custom controller or extension. Your controller could then house whatever complex logic is needed for the Visualforce page.